# What is the use of function.call method?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 10;
var o = { x: 15 };

function f()
{
    alert(this.x);
}

f();
f.call(o);
```

The first one would display me '10' and the second one would display '15' as output value. Can anyone tell in which real time scenario i would use the 'call' method and also the f() at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I was just browsing through unanswered questions, and I'm not sure if this will help you at all but it may help somebody who stumbles upon this question.

Using the `call()` method on a function object allows you to override the *`this`* object to be referenced by the function. You have demonstrated the expected results in your own code block.

It can be noted that the `apply()` method performs pretty much the same functionality of `call()` except for the expected argument formats.

`call()` expects arguments in a comma separated format while `apply()` expects them in an array. With both, the first argument is the object that will be overriding *`this`*.

### ECMA Spec

The [ECMA specification (pdf warning)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) has this to say about `call()` showing its use in changing the execution context for a specific function:

> 13.2.1 [[Call]]
>
> When the [[Call]] internal method for a Function object F is called with a this value and >a list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let funcCtx be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of F's 
>      [[FormalParameters]] internal property, the passed arguments List args, and the this value as described in 
>      10.4.3.
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]] internal property. If 
>      F does not have a [[Code]] internal property or if its value is an empty FunctionBody, then result is (normal, 
>      undefined, empty).
> 3. Exit the execution context funcCtx, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If result.type is throw then throw result.value.
> 5. If result.type is return then return result.value.
> 6. Otherwise result.type must be normal. Return undefined.

Comment: The textbook answer is the only good answer here.  A useful scenario surely exists, but why confine the language structure to one example?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell in which real time scenario i would use the 'call' method and also the f() at the same time.

Functions that are methods of objects are expected to be called with that object as their *this*, e.g. using the built–in *Array.prototype.forEach* method, the method expects *this* to be an Array instance.

However, the method is generic, so the instance doesn't have to be an array, it just has to be an object that is sufficiently like an array for the method to work. In most browsers, it can be passed a NodeList, which is a host object (some browsers don't like this though) so you can call *forEach* passing the NodeList as *this*:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
  function(element){ 
    console.log('This element is a ' + element.tagName)
  }
);
```

Placed in a script element at the bottom of a document, the above will write the tagname of every element to the console.

The call in the above is sometimes shortened to:

```
[].forEach.call(...)
```

which creates a new Array instance and uses its `[[Prototype]]` chain to access *forEach*.

So you can see that there is a need for the plain *forEach* for array instances and a separate use for it with *call*. There are other cases too, where methods can be called with their *this* set to some other value (e.g. listeners on DOM elements).